# Проблема с await в react.js

Tags: reactjs

При использовании await выходит ошибка -  Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function.
Я не понимаю почему запрещает использовать await

```
class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("api")
    const data = await response.json();


    console.log(data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `async componentDidMount() {...`

Answer (score 1):

Стоит просто более внимательно прочесть и перевести ошибку. Использовать ключевое слово await нужно внутри асинхронной функции.
Соответственно

```
async getData () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "api"
  );
  let result = await response.json()
  console.log(result);
};
```

И вызвать эту функцию уже в componentDidMount